# Creating 3D numpy.ndarray with no fixed second dimension

Tags: python, numpy

Sometimes data, such as speech data, have a known number of observations (n), an unknown duration, and a known number of measurements (k).

In the 2D case in NumPy, it is clear how data with a known number of observations (n) and an unknown duration is represented with an ndarray of shape `(n, )`. For example:

```py
import numpy as np

x = np.array([ [ 1, 2 ],
               [ 1, 2, 3 ]
             ])

print(x.shape) ### Returns: (2, )
```

Is there an equivalent for the 3D case in NumPy, where we could have an `ndarray` of shape `(n, , k)`? The best alternative to this I can think of is to have a 2D `ndarray` of shape `(n, )` and have each element also be 2D with a (transpose) shape of `(k, )`. For example,

```py
import numpy as np

x = np.array([ [ [1,2], [1,2] ],
               [ [1,2], [1,2], [1,2] ]
             ])

print(x.shape) ### Returns: (2, ); Desired: (2, , 2)
```

Ideally, a solution would be able to tell us the dimensionality properties of an `ndarray` without the need for a recursive call (maybe with an alternative to `shape`?).

Comment: Your first code snippet is not doing what I think you believe it is doing. When I print the result of it I get `array([array([1, 2, 3]), array([1, 2])], dtype=object)`. This means that you are getting a one dimensional array of objects, which are in this case np.ndarray objects. As for as I am aware it is not possible to allocate an array without a fixed dimension in any direction.

Comment: Define `x` as (2,2) object dtype, and set the the elements from `x1` and `x2`.  But it is tricky to do this without getting broadcasting errors,

Comment: It might be easier to create a (4,) array with list or 1d array elements, and if needed reshape that to (2,2).

Comment: Thank you for the correction, I revised the code with your suggestion.

Comment: @JosephKonan: Your revised code is still a one-dimensional array of object dtype. The inner arrays are just Python lists now instead of NumPy arrays.

Comment: The `(2,)` shape doesn't mean an empty or unknown second dimension. One-element tuples just print like that, because `(2)` would mean `2`, not a tuple. The fact that tuples that print like `(2,)` exist doesn't mean `(2, , 2)` is a thing with any meaning in Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have misunderstood what a shape of `(2,)` means. It doesn't mean `(2, <unknown>)`; the comma is not a separator between `2` and some sort of blank dimension. `(2,)` is the Python syntax for a one-element tuple whose one element is `2`. Python uses this syntax because `(2)` would mean the integer `2`, not a tuple.

You are not creating a two-dimensional array with an arbitrary-length second dimension. You are creating a one-dimensional array of object dtype. Its elements are ordinary Python lists. An array like this is incompatible with almost every useful thing in NumPy.

There is no way to create NumPy arrays with variable-length dimensions, whether in the 2D case you thought worked, or in the 3D case you're trying to make work.

Answer (score 0):

Just to review the 1d case:

```
In [33]: x = np.array([[1,2],[1,2,3]])                                          
In [34]: x.shape                                                                
Out[34]: (2,)
In [35]: x                                                                      
Out[35]: array([list([1, 2]), list([1, 2, 3])], dtype=object)
```

The result is a 2 element array of lists, where as we started with a list of lists.  Not much difference.

But note that if the lists are same size, `np.array` creates a numeric 2d array:

```
In [36]: x = np.array([[1,2,4],[1,2,3]])                                        
In [37]: x                                                                      
Out[37]: 
array([[1, 2, 4],
       [1, 2, 3]])
```

So don't count on the behavior we see in [33].

I could create a 2d object array:

```
In [59]: x = np.empty((2,2),object)                                             
In [60]: x                                                                      
Out[60]: 
array([[None, None],                  # in this case filled with None
       [None, None]], dtype=object)
```

I can assign each element with a different kind and size of object:

```
In [61]: x[0,0] = np.arange(3)                                                  
In [62]: x[0,0] = [1,2,3]                                                       
In [63]: x[1,0] = 'abc'                                                         
In [64]: x[1,1] = np.arange(6).reshape(2,3)                                     
In [65]: x                                                                      
Out[65]: 
array([[list([1, 2, 3]), None],
       ['abc', array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5]])]], dtype=object)
```

It is still 2d.  For most purposes it is like a list or list of lists, containing objects.  The databuffer actually has pointers to objects stored else where in memory (just as list buffer does).

There really isn't such a thing as a 3d array with a variable last dimension.  At best we can get a 2d array that contains lists or arrays of various sizes.

---

Make a list of 2 2d arrays:

```
In [69]: alist = [np.arange(6).reshape(2,3), np.arange(4.).reshape(2,2)]        
In [70]: alist                                                                  
Out[70]: 
[array([[0, 1, 2],
        [3, 4, 5]]), array([[0., 1.],
        [2., 3.]])]
```

In this case, giving it to `np.array` raises an error:
    In [71]: np.array(alist)
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2,3) into shape (2)

We could fill an object array with elements from this list:

```
In [72]: x = np.empty((4,),object)                                              
In [73]: x[0]=alist[0][0]                                                       
In [74]: x[1]=alist[0][1]                                                       
In [75]: x[2]=alist[1][0]                                                       
In [76]: x[3]=alist[1][1]                                                       
In [77]: x                                                                      
Out[77]: 
array([array([0, 1, 2]), array([3, 4, 5]), array([0., 1.]),
       array([2., 3.])], dtype=object)
```

and reshape it to 2d

```
In [78]: x.reshape(2,2)                                                         
Out[78]: 
array([[array([0, 1, 2]), array([3, 4, 5])],
       [array([0., 1.]), array([2., 3.])]], dtype=object)
```

Result is a 2d array containing 1d arrays.  To get the shapes of the elements I have to do something like:

```
In [87]: np.frompyfunc(lambda i:i.shape, 1,1)(Out[78])                          
Out[87]: 
array([[(3,), (3,)],
       [(2,), (2,)]], dtype=object)
```